# Defining Template Content in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What is the recommended way of specifying Ember JS content?

For example, lets say I have a table and the table has certain columns on the web page.

Where would I specify the title of the table and the columns of the table?

Currently, at my company, developers will store JSON with all the content for the table. For instance, they will create a table class in Python on the backend with something like:

```
class UserTable(object):

  table_title = 'This is the table title'

  columns = ['user', 'first name', 'title']

  rows = [['test_user', 'John', 'Software Engineer']]
```

This seems almost like we are delegating the presentation logic to the backend. Is there a better place to be defining the contents of the table for instance, the title of the table? Is this bad practice in Ember?

Comment: Doesn't seem so bad to me.

Comment: That seems a little fishy to me, too.  What does the data look like that is being sent to you?  Usually, when we're using a table in our Ember app, the columns are the properties of a model and the rows enumerate each instance of that class.  I think you're right, this should be a client-side concern.